# How to get the value of textbox which is in side an Anchor Tag using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, anchor

I have a textbox inside the anchor tag. And I want to get its value using JavaScript.
My code is

```
<a rel="tooltip" title="This information comes from the Income/Expense worksheet.">
  <span class="TooltipTextBox">    
          <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Helo" runat="server" CssClass="small_text_box"  ReadOnly="true" TabIndex="-1" BackColor="#CCCCCC" size="15">
          </asp:TextBox>
  </span>
```

Comment: @limelights - Great link! And so true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to figure out the client ID of the textbox. Actually this ID is independent from wether the text box is wrapped inside an acnhor or not. Therefore you can either use ASP.NET and do the following:

```
<script>var clientID = "<%=txt_hello.ClientID%>"</script>
```

Then you can access the text box with the ID:

```
<script>var txtBoxElement = document.getElementById(clientID);</script>
```

And then you can access the value of txtBoxElement.

The other approach would be purely JS based but you wouldn't know the exact client ID so use for instance jQuery to utilise css selectors:

```
<script>var textBoxVal = $("a span.TooltipTextBox input").val();</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise JQuery(edit: If you are using more JS on your site and not just using it to get this value). If you just want the text this should work:

```
var Text = $("#<%= txt_Helo.ClientID %>").val();
```

Basically, you access the TextBox using the ID ASP.NET has assigned to that control.

Without JQuery:

```
var Text = document.getElementById("<%= txt_Helo.ClientID %>").value;
```

Comment: you would advise jQuery to get the value of a text box?! One has to wonder, what *wouldn't you advise jQuery for? When all you have is a hammer, pretty soon every problem starts to look like a nail. You don't need a massive javascript framework when you can just toss in 1 line of javascript!

Comment: You use `.val()` to get the value of an element, not `.text()`.

Comment: @Dr. A few KB is massive? Ok. Have also included an answer without JQuery. Also clarified the usage of JQuery.

Comment: a wasted byte is still a wasted byte, and a wasted cpu cycle is a wasted cpu cycle.  If jQuery offered some really meaningful advantage here, it would be fine, but in this situation it's an extra http call and wasted bloat, for no reason at all. Thanks for adding the jQueryless option. It's the correct one, in this situation.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - No one builds a website/webapp that just gets the value of a textbox and nothing more, no more JavaScript whatsoever on the page. One would hope that if you're building something valuable in the modern Web, you're using lots of JavaScript, and one would hope you're using libraries that make working with that JavaScript a lot easier and more efficient. Plus, this isn't 1984, computers are quite powerful these days, so worrying about a wasted CPU cycle, in most cases, is more time wasted than gained.

Comment: @jmort253, jQuery is only useful for a tiny fraction of what people build. It's true that this is changing rapidly, and more and more sites are becoming robust applications, however, that doesn't change the fact that this particular question doesn't begin to rise to where one would rationally employ jQuery. I have written tens of thousands of lines of javascript over the last 15 years and have used jQuery exactly 3 times (with much success).  I think it's entirely reasonable to keep jQuery out of the mix until its specific strengths are actually called for.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't have to do anything more than this in asp.net

```
var value = document.getElementById('<% =txt_Helo.ClientID %>').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with asp, so, not sure what `<asp:TextBox>` produces, but if it has an id, why does it matter that it's a child to an anchor? why not just get its value using its id?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted as you are correct. However, ASP.NET assigns IDs at runtime - something like `ct100_something_txt_Helo` (based on the hierachy of the control) so you access it via `<% =txt_Helo.ClientID %>`

Comment: I downvoted because the answer is just a series of questions that don't really explain how to solve the problem. Consider editing to make it clear, and leave a comment, and I'll gladly remove the downvote :)  This answer is vague and doesn't clarify whether I use the actual ID on the ASP element ("txt_Helo") or use the generated HTML element.

Comment: jmort "why not just get its value using its id?" is actually a suggestion, even though it has a ? at the end. Perhaps English isn't your first language (it's not mine either), but there is, in fact, a suggestion (and as it happens, the correct one) in my answer. However, I appreciate you down voting it, as that has resulted in someone else up-voting it, and earning me 8 points.